# Remove scientific notation formatting for Float values in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, number-formatting

I am trying to set the float value to an edit text. For this I am using a binding adapter like this below.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
@JvmStatic
fun setAmount(editText: EditText, currency: Float?) {
    if (currency!= null && currency!=0.0f) {

       editText.setText(""+Math.round(currency))
    }else{
        editText.setText("")
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
class OpportunityModel : BaseObservable(), Serializable {

var accountName = ""
var accountGuid: String? = null
var amount = 0.0
var potentialAmount:Float = 0.0f
get() = field
set(value) {field=value}
var contactPersonName = ""
var fieldOne = ""
var fieldTwo = ""
var fieldThree = ""
var fieldFour = ""
var fieldFive = ""
var opportunityName = ""
var opportunityGuid: String? = null
var opportunityRating = 0
var opportunityReasonGuid: String? = null
var opportunityIntStatus = 2
var opportunityDispStatus = ""
var opportunityNotAvailable = false
var genericFieldUI: GenericFieldDto? = null
@SerializedName("expDateOfClosure")
var dateForServer: String? = null
var expDate = ""
var contactPersonNameGuid: String? = null
var listOfAccountContact = ArrayList<AccountContactPersonModel>()
var listOfReasonMaster = ArrayList<ReasonMasterDto>()}
```

This shows the value properly in the edit text but when this value is added to the model class via data binding, it gets converted to scientific notation and is showing values like `1E+07`. How can I stop this conversion to scientific notation ?

Comment: Can you put your model class or specific part of the model class?

Comment: @SomeshKumar added

Comment: Try using double instead of float on both the model and the binding adapter and see if the problem resolves

Comment: @SomeshKumar I was using double before. That too was having the same issue

Comment: then try using BigDecimal and turn floats into String and use BigDecimal's toPlainString method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.format, like

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
@JvmStatic
fun setAmount(editText: EditText, currency: Float?) {
    if (currency!= null && currency!=0.0f) {

       editText.setText(String.format("%.8f", currency))
    }else{
        editText.setText("")
    }
}
```

Comment: `%.2f` might rather be suitable for fiat currencies.